# js Clicking on the table columns, it does not sort data

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table, datatable, datatables

**Q: Clicking on the table columns, it does not sort data**

I might have inadvertently modified the datatable built-in functionality, causing the original sorting feature to disappear.

- [demo video](https://imgur.com/a/O9oXGRY)

```
function modalTable_WEBAPI_alarm() {
  const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  var getData;
  var rowData;
  var currentPage = 1;
  var saved_json_rowData = [];
  newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");

  var datatable_WEBAPI_alarm = $("#id_datatable_WEBAPI_alarm").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: newValue + '/api/message/list',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
      },
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',

      data: function (d) {
        d.search = d.search.value;
        d.sf = 'S05F01';
        console.log("RES SF", d);

        return JSON.stringify(d);
      },

    },
    destroy: true,

    columns: [
      { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
      { data: "code", title: "code" },
      { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
      { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" },
      { data: "description", title: "description_webapi_alarm" },
      {
        data: null,
        title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + row.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
          var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
          var isChecked = row.webapi ? 'checked' : ''; // Check if rowData.webapi is true, then add the checked attribute
          switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="webapi_' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
          switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="webapi_' + switchId + '">Selected</label>';
          switchHTML += '</div>';
          return switchHTML;
        },
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + rowData.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
          var switchElement = $(td).find('#webapi_' + switchId);
          // console.log("WEBAPI Element: ", switchElement);
          var isChecked = rowData.webapi ? 'checked' : ''; // Set the isChecked variable based on rowData.webapi
          switchElement.change(function () {
            console.log("WEBAPI switchId: ", switchId);
            console.log("WEBAPI isChecked: ", $(this).prop('checked'));
            console.log("getData Add this output: ", getData); // Add this output
            console.log("WEBAPI switchElement: ", switchElement);
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

              console.log(":checked triggered before", rowData);
              rowData.webapi = true;
              rowData.isChanged = true;

              console.log(":checked triggered after", rowData);

              saved_json_rowData.push(Object.assign({}, rowData)); // Add a copy of rowData to the saved_json_rowData array

            } else {
              console.log(":checked triggered ");
              rowData.webapi = false;
              rowData.isChanged = true;
              saved_json_rowData.push(Object.assign({}, rowData)); // Add a copy of rowData to the saved_json_rowData array
            }

            var selectedRows = datatable_WEBAPI_alarm.rows({ selected: true }).data();
            console.log("Selected Rows >>>>>", selectedRows);
            webapi_server.data = selectedRows.map(function (row) {
              return { id: row.id, enable: row.webapi };
            });
            webapi_server.length = webapi_server.data.length;
            webapi_server.server = "webapi";
            console.log("Selected Rows:", webapi_server);
            // var changedData = saved_json_rowData.filter(item => item.isChanged == true);
            var changedData = saved_json_rowData.filter(item => item.isChanged === true);

            console.log("saved_json_rowData: ", saved_json_rowData);
            // console.log("rowData: ", rowData);
            console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);


            // Convert changedData to the required format
            var changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0 = changedData.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              enable: item.webapi
            }));
            console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0", changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0);

            // Add the converted data to the target object
            changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi = {
              draw: 1,
              length: changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0.length,
              server: "webapi",
              data: changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0
            };
            console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi:", changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi);

          });
        },
      ],
      initComplete: function (settings, json) {
        getData = json.data.filter(obj => obj.sf === 'S05F01').map(obj => {
          let result = { ...obj }; // Deep copy the object using the object spread operator
          result['isChanged'] = false; // Assign the variable
          return result;
        });
      }

    });

  // Initialize the tabs in the WEBAPI modal
  $('#webapiTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });

}
```

I've been looking at it for quite a while but couldn't find the issue. I hope export who knowledgeable can provide some guidance ⁽⁽◝( •ω• )◜⁾⁾.